# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'fn' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Tags: javascript, iife

I know how to fix this error but does anyone tell me a comprehensive explanation of why this error occurs?

```
var fn = function () {
  return fn();
}(); //uncaught TypeError: Property 'fn' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the var keyword in the global scope, the declared variable becomes a property of the global object.  In a web browser, the global object is the `window` object, which itself is an instance of `DOMWindow()`.  So, using that knowledge we can rewrite your code to look like this:

```
window.fn = function () {
    return window.fn();
}();
```

Taking away the initial assignment, we have

```
(function () {
    return window.fn();
})();
```

...which defines an anonymous function wherein `window.fn()` is called.  However, at the point this code runs, `window.fn` is not a function (and never will be), so an exception is thrown because you're trying to invoke it even though it doesn't have an internal `[[Call]]` flag.

If you take away the immediate execution of the anonymous function, then `window.fn` would be a function:

```
var fn = function () {
    return fn();
}
fn(); //-> infinite loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fn = function () {
  return fn();
}();
```

1. The above code is a variable statement. The variable `fn` is declared an it's value i set to `undefined` (for now).
2. `function () {}()` is an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). An IIFE is a function which is invoked immediately.
3. That IIFE contains one statement - a `return` statement. Since the IIFE has been invoked, that `return` statement is executed immediately.
4. That `return` statement contains this expression: `fn()` - it's a function invocation. But what is `fn` at this moment? Is it a function? No. It's still `undefined`. Invoking the `undefined` value will throw an error.

---

I assume you probably want to achieve the this pattern:

```
var fn = (function () {

    var private = 0;

    function utility() { ... }

    return function () { ... };

})();
```

Now, `fn` is a function which has exclusive access to the `private` variable and the `utility` private function.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is

1. Execute the function `function () { return fn(); }`
2. Store the returned value in a variable called `fn`

Trouble is, of course, that when #1 is happening, `fn` hasn't been defined yet, so the function call can't use it; `fn` is not function. It's the same as saying "set the value of X to the value of X", which doesn't make sense.

Except you're actually trying to return *the result* of calling `fn`, which makes even less sense. So even if it somehow didn't complain about `fn` not being defined yet, you'd still get an infinite recursion where the function call returns the returned value of the returned value of the returned value …
As Shef says, that's what's called a stack overflow error

Answer (score -2):

```
var fn = function () {
  return this;
}();
```

---

You can't write that, because variable type function definition is not elaborated before the other code. Besides what you are trying to do makes no sense. You could create the function like:

```
function fn(){
    return fn();
}

fn();
```

But you are going to hit a `stack_overflow` error.

Comment: -1 (1) Doesn't answer the question, which is "Why can't I write this?" not "What should I write instead?". (2) I don't think this has anything to do with OP's code, your version is just an elaborate way to write `var fn = window;`.

Comment: @delnan: I hope you are satisfied now.